# How to use Command Object on Controller (Grails 2.3.11) for update?

Tags: object, grails, command

For example, I have a controller 'AddressTestController', and it has function update that accepts a Command Object.

```
AddressTestController
{
    def update(AddressUpdateCommand cmd){}
}

class AddressUpdateCommand
{
    String firstName
    String address
}
```

When 'firstName' is not in the body request, it's null. When it has value null, it's also null. How do I check if a user wants its value to be null? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can't differ between empty and not submitted values in a command.

The only difference would be, that default values should be applied if a value is not submitted.

```
class AddressUpdateCommand
{
    String firstName = "firstName was not submitted"
    String address
}
```